# Tomcat 9 class loading issue with Jaxb-impl& jaxb-runtime

Tags: java, jaxb

Jaxb-api and jaxb-runtime has the same package with the same class name called
RuntimeModelBuilder and same interface with same package Navigator interface.

So one jar is calling the other jar class and ends up in a "class not found" exception...

Any idea how to fix it... the same issue does not come in tomcat 7...

Comment: A class cannot be named `RUNTIMEMODELBUILDER.JAVA`, so that cannot be true. Try again.

Comment: Its the name used in those jars...you can download jars and verify

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66442158/edit) your question and provide the versions of the libraries you are using, Java's version and the exact exception you obtain. A useful tool is [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/).

Comment: Nope, in file `jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar`, I see a class named `RuntimeModelBuilder` in package `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl`. I see no class named `RUNTIMEMODELBUILDER.JAVA` which is good, because class names cannot have `.` and should not be in all uppercase. So my original comment stands: Please try again, because what you wrote in the question is blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

have you tired
JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS --add-modules=java.xml.bind"

the class only available

> jaxb-impl-2.2_1.jar

com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.class

Comment: The problem is the class is available  in 2 jars...with same packageName as i mentioned above....lets say tomcat loaded these 2 jars...2nd jar dependencies should be looked in 2nd jar but as same class with pkg so its looking in first jar and failing...

Comment: If multiple versions of the same class are on the same classpath, a `ClassNotFoundException` will **never** occur. You just get a random version of the class.